# How to prevent from textmeshpro input field text to be all selected/highlighted?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is what I have tried:

```
private void LoadFromFile()
{
    if (File.Exists(savePath))
    {
        inputField.text = File.ReadAllText(savePath);
        // Update line number based on loaded text
        UpdateLineNumber(inputField.text);

        if (inputField.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            // Wait for the next frame when the inputField is active in the hierarchy, then reset caret
            StartCoroutine(ResetCaretPosition());
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator ResetCaretPosition()
{
    yield return null; // Wait for the next frame
                       // Prevent text from being selected/highlighted
    if (inputField != null)
    {
        inputField.caretPosition = 0; // Sets the caret position to the beginning of the text
        inputField.selectionAnchorPosition = 0; // Resets the selection anchor position
        inputField.selectionFocusPosition = 0; // Resets the selection focus position
    }
}
```

and using it calling the LaodFromFile()

```
private void InitializeNotePad()
{
    inputField.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "notes.txt");
    if (deleteFileOnStart)
    {
        if(File.Exists(savePath))
        {
            File.Delete(savePath);
        }
    }
    LoadFromFile();
}
```

and in Start

```
private void Start()
{
    InitializeNotePad();
}
```

it's getting to the code inside the Coroutine and doing all the settings to value 0 but still all the text is being selected/highlighted when the input field get active.

Comment: There is an option in TMP that says "OnFocus - Select All". You probably want to uncheck it.